# Improved Levenshtein Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I recently implemented the levenshtein algorithm into our search engine database, but we have come across a problem.

According to the basic levenshtein

Levenshtein('123456','12x456') is the same value as Levenshtein('123456', '12345x')

Normally this is fine, but for my specific problem that is incorrect. When someone uses our website, this is incorrect. Manufacturers of electronic components often make similar products with only a difference in the very last letter. If the first letter is different, it's usually an entirely different category. Therefore I need an algorithm that considers matches near the beginning of the word more valuable than those in the back or in other words, mismatches that occur near the beginning should apply a larger penalty than those in the back.

If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Comment: What did you try to improve the algorithm?

Comment: I tried adding weights to the mismatch based on the location of the letter in the sequence (higher weights for those in front), but it resulted in undesirable outcomes. I was looking for something more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue and used the [Brew edit distance method](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~cbrew/795M/string-distance.html)

We were in Perl so we used the [Text::Brew](http://search.cpan.org/~kcivey/Text-Brew-0.02/lib/Text/Brew.pm) library.  My co-worker did a nice presentation on using a [few different algorithms](http://www.slideshare.net/kyleburton/fuzzy-string-matching), including Brew.

Comment: This looks promising as it considers different weights for different mismatches allowing for inserts to be less expensive than deletes or subsitutions, but how can this be applied to consider word order important? The example i have is this. There is a partnumber 1-480424-0. The result 1-480424-8 should be higher than 1-430424-0 if i searched for 1-480424-0.

Comment: A key point is that you can obtain the description of the edits needed to transform the first string into the second.  For example, in our world (matching names of things), the beginning of the string was much more important, so we used brew mainly to get access to a path and then sorted based on that path, ranking things at the beginning of the string higher than at the end.  The key is that we got back the path, not just an edit distance number.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Ok I will see what I can do with that information. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: So I came up with my own solution which seems to work quite well. In the normal Levenshtein you apply a cost of 1 when mismatches occur. What i did was instead apply a cost of 1 - Min(i,j)/(2 * MAX(m,n)) where i and j are the current values we are looking at and m and n are the lengths of the two words. You can also use Max(i,j) instead as it produces similar results.

Comment: The "Brew edit distance method" is nothing more than the well-known Wagner-Fischer algorithm. Chris Brew is not the author of the original algorithm and would prefer to not have his name inappropriately associated with it. The algorithm has apparently been discovered and rediscovered multiple times independently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm#History.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Smith-Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) algorithm widely used in bioinformatics. It can perform a local alignment of your query, but that will be slower that Levenshtein.

Comment: Hmm, it might be too slow. We have over 200,000 rows to search over and the levenshtein already takes about 400ms. Thank you for this information. I hope there is a modified levenshtein though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Jaro-Winkler Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro-Winkler_distance)... It's exactly what you are asking for.